# how to open and close the Bootstrap modal pop inside directive link function?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-directive, angular-services

I need to open the bootstrap modal pop up inside directive under some function , how could do with in directive.

Instead of these need to use angualr to open dialog.

```
 var show = function () {
                    $('#myModal1').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
                    $element.css('display', 'block');

                };
```

Like as need to hide with angular

```
 var hide = function () {
                    $('#myModal1').modal(toggle);
                    $element.css('display', 'none');
                };


myApp.directive('loadingStatusMessage', function () {
        return {
            link: function ($scope, $element, attrs) {
                var show = function () {
                    $('#myModal1').modal({ backdrop: 'static', keyboard: false });
                    $element.css('display', 'block');

                };
                var hide = function () {
                    $('#myModal1').modal(toggle);
                    $element.css('display', 'none');
                };
                $scope.$on('loadingStatusActive', show);
                $scope.$on('loadingStatusInactive', hide);
                hide();
            }
        };
    });
```

html:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
     aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" loading-status-message
     style="position:fixed; display:none;">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <button type="button" class="close"
                            data-dismiss="modal"
                            aria-label="Close">
                       <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                        <strong>Technical Error Occurred.Please contact the System Administrator for the further support!!</strong>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Put a brief summary of the problem in the title of your question.

Comment: @georgeawg i need to show the bootstarp modal pop up with some message ,so i have written a directive , in directive  i will use jquery to open the pop up, instead of that need to open the dialog with angular.just look the html.